# Обработать строку с помощью регулярного выражения на Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.5

Задача: нужно отбросить из начала данной строки все символы, не являющимися буквами, до первой встретившийся буквы. Исключительно используя регулярное выражение.

Например:
s = "12. Привет мир 23 раза"

Должно остаться "Привет мир 23 раза"

Пробовал как то так

```
re.match(r'(?<=(\d|\.|\s)*)(.*)', s).group()
```

не получается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль регулярных выражений Python `re` не поддерживает блоков предварительного просмотра назад неопределенной длины. В `(?<=(\d|\.|\s)*)` длина совпадения неопределена, так как квантификатор `*` находит ноль и более (неизвестно сколько) символов.

Используйте

```
re.sub(r'^[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]+', '', s)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/kI8pC6/1)

Подробности:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от русских букв. Если надо, можно включить и латинские - `[^а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+`.

**Примечание**:

Символ `^` в разных контекстах может обозначать:

- *Буквальный символ `^` (caret)*:

  - Если он экранирован знаком `\` (в любом месте регулярного выражения)
  - Если он находится внутри символьного класса *не в начальной позиции* (т.е. `[;!^]`)
  - (В некоторых других языках / библиотеках ещё может быть между `\Q` ... `\E`)
- *Метасимвол начала строки/целого текста* (в зависимости от модификатора или библиотеки регулярных выражений, в Python при использовании `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` - позиция после знака перевода строки LF, `\n`, если модификатор не указан, будет найдено только начало целого текста)

  - Если он не экранирован **и** не находится внутри символьного класса
- *Метасимвол, инвертирующий символьный класс*, т.е. `[^.]` найдёт все символы, отличные от точки.

**ВНИМАНИЕ**!  [`[^^]`](https://regex101.com/r/pC8dW1/1) находит любой символ, отличный от знака `^`

Comment: А почему не `re.sub("^[\d\s.]*","",s);` оно проще и в точности отвечает набору символов указанных автором вопроса

Comment: @Mike: Я смотрю не на выражение ТС, а на описание задачи - *нужно отбросить из начала данной строки все символы, не являющимися буквами, до первой встретившийся буквы*. Что-то, что не является чем-то, отлавливается с помощью инвертированных символьных классов типа `[^....]`

Comment: В первом случае символ "^" используется как начало строки, а во втором как отрицание? Если да, то какое существует правило, для значения этого символа, в зависимости от его положения?

Comment: Я добавил описание символа `^`.